Do high-energy conformers allow for more flexibility in ligand binding?
After reading, "High Energy Conformer - Why is it the most stable?" which is at risk of being closed due to lack of detail, I'm curious whether my thoughts on reasons for selecting a high-energy conformer are correct.
When conducting docking studies on ligands using RDKit and plotting their respective potential energies, it was recommended that the researcher use the high-energy conformer for docking to a protein target. An intuitive choice might be to choose a low-energy conformer instead as it would generally be more stable.
My thoughts: A high-energy conformation would give the ligand "room" for conformational changes after it forms the ligand, where this might not be possible if you're already at a minimum.
Alternatively (or additionally), if the ligand is already in its lowest energy conformation, it might be less likely to bind because there is no "flexibility" left for necessary adjustments for the bond to form in the first place.
Are my thoughts on this correct?


A high-energy conformation would give the ligand "room" for
conformational changes after it forms the ligand, where this might not
be possible if you're already at a minimum.

Not correct, if the reaction is "docking" as stated in the linked question. The conformation is supposed to be similar before and after the docking reaction.

Alternatively (or additionally), if the ligand is already in its
lowest energy conformation, it might be less likely to bind because
there is no "flexibility" left for necessary adjustments for the bond
to form in the first place.

This is almost correct in specific cases. The case in the linked question must have been described by "case II" in this wikipedia article: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curtin%E2%80%93Hammett_principle#Case_II:_Less_stable_conformer_reacts_more_quickly despite the claim in the linked Q:

It has nothing to do with my molecular systems, etc.

To conclude, the linked question is confusing the energies of the reactants (ligands before docking) and products (metastable local minima of docked protein-ligand complex). The high energy of the former can, in this case, lead to low energy of the latter (or maybe just deeper local minimum).
